# Is this an independent or a dependent clause?

Tags: grammar, sentence, clauses, dependent-clause, independent-clauses

Is this an independent or a dependent clause?

> You will have to fly from Copenhagen.

Comment: The sentence consists of a matrix clause (the sentence as a whole) with two embedded dependent clauses.

Answer (score -1):

In a comment, BillJ wrote:

> The sentence consists of a matrix clause (the sentence as a whole) with two embedded dependent clauses.

Comment: In traditional grammar _You will have to fly from Copenhagen_ would be considered an independent clause. I would be interested in a more detailed account which identifies the two dependent clauses, together with a link to a definitive resource on this alternative analysis.